# jquery validation error message is showing, but form is getting submitted

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, validation

jquery validation error message is showing, but form is getting submitted
I tried using `e.preventdefault()` but it didn't work.
no errors are showing in console.

```
$('#btn_sub').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($("#user_add").valid()){
    var adddata = new FormData(document.getElementById("user_add"));

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: base_url+'admin/shift/add_shift',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data : adddata,
            async: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,

            success:function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById("user_add").reset();
                $('#model_add').modal('hide');
                show_product();
            },
            error:function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert("Internal Error: Contact Administrator");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. You seem to have some mis-matched braces in the code above

Comment: I suppose it should be `e.prevenDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn_sub').click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();
if(!$("#user_add").valid()){
    return false;
}
var adddata = new FormData(document.getElementById("user_add"));

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: base_url+'admin/shift/add_shift',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data : adddata,
        async: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById("user_add").reset();
            $('#model_add').modal('hide');
            show_product();
        },
        error:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert("Internal Error: Contact Administrator");
        }
    });
```

});

make sure that your validation are correct

Comment: Da justin is there any other solutions. Validation message varunud ,apo thane data submit aakunu. e.preventDefault() oke try chythu.   if(!$("#user_add").valid()){
    return false;
}             tried but not working.

Comment: can you send the full code to justinjoseph287@gmail.com

Comment: It was fixed.I used   submitHandler: function(form) { update_oldShift(); }.

Answer (score 0):

You must try this -

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
});
```